# Looking for ... the Generalized Fisher-Tippett distribution

Tags: distributions, extreme-value

so I would like to use a parametric model that smoothly interpolates between the 3-parameter Weibull, the 3-parameter Frechet and the 3-parameter Gumbel. 
Just like the  Fisher-Tippett distribution (a.k.a. Generalised Extreme Value distribution) smoothly interpolates between the 2-parameter versions of the Weibull, Frechet and Gumbel.

According to the "Field Guide to Continuous Probability Distributions" by Gavin E. Crooks pg. there should be a generalisation of the GEV with 2 shape parameters (4 parameters in total) that can do what the GEV can do for its 2-parameter subfamilies, but for the 3-parameter cases.

This Generalized Fisher-Tippett distribution, does it exist or is it some theoretical construct?
Can someone point me to the right direction if such an analytic model exist?

Comment: Interesting: [Amoroso distribution](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.3274.pdf).

Comment: Interesting indeed. May be closely related to what I want. Thanks

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question correctly, but there are quite a few practical implementations for the GEV distribution. In the ismev package in R, you can find the Port Pirie dataset which is commonly used as an example of data that follows the GEV distribution @vzografos